# is there a way in snowflake to log errors while copying data from internal stage to a table if i am using JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

i am trying to do internal stage loading in snowflake using my java code for that i have used snowflake's JDBC connector . i am loading files to a table using copy command so is there a way to log errors while copying and store those records in a seperate error table.
I am adding the code snippet where i am copying the file from internal stage to a table.
i am trying to log error rows in a seperate table. while copying a file from internal stage to a table

```
 Connection cp = connection.getConnection();
>           Statement stm = cp.createStatement();  
>     
>     
>     stm.executeUpdate("copy into "+table+" from @int_stage File_format=(format_name=fileformat_csv) ON_ERROR='continue'");
>               stm.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Snowflake provides a native function to return load activity (with or without error) : [COPY_HISTORY](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/copy_history.html).

Answer (score 0):

One more option to use is:

```
select * from table(validate(t1, job_id=>'5415fa1e-59c9-4dda-b652-533de02fdcf1'));
```

and if you want to create log error table from above query , you can also use

```
create or replace table errors_table_name as select * from table(validate(t1, job_id=>'5415fa1e-59c9-4dda-b652-533de02fdcf1'));
```